# trying to scrape data of json in php not working

Tags: php, arrays, json

why won't this work it should scrape the definition for pp and it won't work :/

```
<?php
$json_output = file_get_contents("http://api.urbandictionary.com/v0/define?term=pp");
$json = json_decode($json_output, true);
$chuck_noris = $json['list']['definition'];
print_r($chuck_noris );
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is still dimension inside `$json['list']` *(Its still an array)*. You can use foreach to get to those values inside it:

```
$json_output = file_get_contents("http://api.urbandictionary.com/v0/define?term=pp");
$json = json_decode($json_output, true);
foreach($json['list'] as $list) {
    // $list will hold each array inside `$json['list']`
    echo $list['definition'] . '<br/>';
}
```

Or explicitly pointing to the first result:

```
echo $json['list'][0]['definition'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your api outputs few arrays and list is one of them to access the content of list do the following

```
foreach($json->list as $something)
{
$chuck_noris = $something->definition;
echo $chuck_noris;
}
```